# Что есть big-data?

Tags: sql, терминология, big-data

Много где видел такое понятие, как big-data. Только вот не совсем понятно, насколько data, с которой ты работаешь, должна быть big, что бы её можно было считать big-data? Объем ли это всего хранилища, или же это данные, которые может возвращать, к примеру, один запрос?

Comment: Жесткой границы нет. Если данные нельзя обработать на одной машине за разумное время - это big data :)

Comment: Обычно, когда говорят о big-data, говорят скорее не об объеме данных, а в подходах к их обработке и хранению. Может быть бигдата на 100мб )

Comment: @Viktorov в этом случае особый подход к обработке не оправдан и его использование начинает больше соответствовать термину "глупость", чем "bigdata".

Comment: Если привычные средства обработки информации и вертикальное масштабирование перестают справляться с потоком информации, то настает время переходить на big-data и горизонтальное масштабирование.

Comment: Это маркетинговая шумелка (buzzword), которая применяется когда удобно.

Comment: big-data, это в первую очередь алгоритмы, позволяющие как то структурировать РАЗНОРОДНУЮ информацию. Для того что бы они работали информации должно быть МНОГО, и тем больше, чем более разнородная информация у вас в наличие.

Comment: Дискуси:я под вопросом не пролила ясности. Кто-нибудь дайте вразумительный отает.